# Can't get rails to eat the nested forms I require

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

The full range of relevant code is [here](https://gist.github.com/4ac6cb3927c1ea0d7915).

My problem is, I am trying to rebuild something from [Railscast 196](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1), to get multiple nested forms in my form for `Campaign`. Every `Campaign` can have one or more teams attached to it, via `CampaignTeam`. Also, the `Campaign` is dependent on a client, without it, it can't exist.

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :clients do
  resources :campaigns
end
```

Now, with the above code (I didn't want to clutter this question with it), I get an error: `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: campaign_team`. When I add `attr_accessible :campaign_team` then I get `unknown attribute: campaign_team`.

How can I get rails to finally eat this form and just nest an Array of `CampaignTeam` with a single member? Where am I doing wrong here?

(Sorry been at this single form for three hours now and very frustrated)

Comment: Have you tried using `:campaign_team_id`?  Rails defaults to the postfix `_id` for foreign keys... Should also change the input name to that as well.

Comment: But the problem is that I don't even *have* `:campaign_team`. Only `:campaign_teams` - the plural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. In the controller, I changed in the controller

```
def new
  @client = Client.find params[:client_id]
  @campaign = @client.campaigns.build
  @campaign.campaign_teams.build          # New line
end
```

and then changed the `new.html.haml` line 15 to

```
=f.fields_for :campaign_teams do |b|
```

Not it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just adding existing teams, you can do with a collection_select, and add

```
attr_accessible :teams_ids
```

On the other side, if you need to create teams, you'll need

```
accept_nested_attributes_for :teams
```

(all this depends that you have set `has_many :teams, :through => :campaign_teams` in the `Campaign` class)

Comment: The problem ist that `CampaignTeams` holds additional information about the relation that needs to be set in the form, too, for each `Team`.

Comment: then do the same to both levels: `accept_nested_attributes_for :campaign_teams` in Campaign, and `attr_accessible :team_id` in CampaignTeam. Then nest the form for the CampaignTeam instance, with a select for the team_id.

Comment: Nope, still getting `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: campaign_team`.